# Excel: Partial multi-column match to parent column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spread-sheet that has food ingredient preferences listed along with the person it applies to, and a list of meals and the ingredients they contain - I'm looking for some way to check each of the meal ingredients against the preferences and return a list of the people that could have any of those ingredients as a preference.

[The gray area is the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpvFV.png)

My initial idea was (for cell E5):

```
{=INDEX($A:$A,LARGE((ISNUMBER(FIND(E$2,$B$2:$B$7))+ISNUMBER(FIND(E$3,$B$2:$B$7))>0)*ROW($B$2:$B$7),ROW(A12)-ROW($A$11)))}
```

which mostly works, but as I plan on having more ingredients per meal it gets really unwieldy really quickly...

Any ideas on how to streamline this so it can be expanded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is to build up a 2d array where the rows are your people and the columns are the ingredients for each dish. Where the person likes one of the ingredients, you get a TRUE value in the array from ISNUMBER(SEARCH) in the same way as your formula. If you want to find if the person likes *any* of the ingredients for the particular dish, you can use a standard method to get the row totals of the array using MMULT and then use LARGE and INDEX the same way you did.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,LARGE(IF(MMULT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(E$2:E$4),$B$2:$B$10))*(TRANSPOSE(E$2:E$4)<>""),ROW(E$2:E$4))>0,ROW($A$2:$A$10)),ROWS(E$5:E5))),"")
```

This has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You could also use SMALL if you wanted them listed in their original order.

[image]

Comment: I'm using the MMULT formula and its perfect, thanks! Plus there's a few functions you've used that I'm not familiar with (MMULT, TRANSPOSE, N) which I can use in some of my other projects to refine them!

Comment: Yes there are useful functions. Plz note that I altered my original formula to add checking for blank cells in the ingredients list *(TRANSPOSE(E$2:E$4)<>"") . Because the result of the multiplication should always be a number I was able to remove the n() function whose only purpose was to convert true/false to 1/0 (the values fed in to mmult have to be numbers)..